# How can you manually reload a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I have the following code in my Auth factory:

```
login: function(user) {
  return $http
    .post('/login', user)
    .then(function(response) {
      Session.setUser(response.data);
      $cookies.put('userId', response.data._id);
      $state.go('home', { reload: true });
      // $window.location.href = '/';
    })
  ;
},
```

The problem is that my navbar doesn't get updated (I have properties in the view that are data bound to `vm.currentUser`; see below). It does when I use `$window.location.href = '/'`, but doing that messes up my tests.

I figure that the solution would be to manually reload the navbar directive. How can I do that? This is what the directive currently looks like:

```
angular
  .module('mean-starter')
  .directive('navbar', navbar)
;

function navbar() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: '/components/navbar/navbar.directive.html',
    controller: NavbarController,
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  };
}

function NavbarController(Auth) {
  var vm = this;
  Auth
    .getCurrentUser()
    .then(function(currentUser) {
      vm.currentUser = currentUser;
    })
  ;
  vm.logout = function() {
    Auth.logout();
  };
}
```

Comment: When you login, you do `Session.setUser`. Can you show the code of how this user is related to the user returned by `Auth.getCurrentUser()`? It might be possible your `NavbarController` is referencing a different 'currentUser` object

Answer (score 0):

ok, after you explained further what is broken I noticed that the problem is that in your factory you are not properly returning the deferred promise like `deferred.resolve`. I should explain, I'm specifically looking around the question of how to "manually reload a directive" because you should not have to manually reload a directive, that's an antipattern. Directives should take care of themselves.

I made a demo. After the proper Auth factory finishing it's thing, with `deferred.resolve` the directive updates all on it's own because the bound model has changed. Check it out, it solves your problem:

http://plnkr.co/edit/u1FakV?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.factory('Auth', ['$timeout', '$q',
  function($timeout, $q) {
    function getCurrentUserFake() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      setTimeout(function() {
        deferred.resolve('Joe Smith');
      }, 1000);
      return deferred.promise;
    }

    function getCurrentUser() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $http.get('/login')
        .success(function(data) {
          deferred.resolve(data)
        })
        .error(function(data) {
          deferred.reject(data);
        });
      return deferred.promise;
    }
    return {
      getCurrentUser: getCurrentUser,
      getCurrentUserFake: getCurrentUserFake
    };
  }
]);

app.directive('navbar', navbar);

function navbar() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div>{{vm.currentUser}}</div>',
    controller: NavbarController,
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  };
}

function NavbarController(Auth) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.currentUser = 'logging in...';
  Auth
    .getCurrentUserFake()
    .then(function(currentUser) {
      console.log(currentUser);
      vm.currentUser = currentUser;
    });
  vm.logout = function() {
    Auth.logout();
  };
}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.3"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <navbar></navbar>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: That doesn't work and I wouldn't expect it to work. How would the digest cycle update the value of `vm.user`?

Comment: hmm, guess I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "my navbar doesn't get updated". What exactly doesn't get updated?

Comment: Oh sorry, I should have clarified - `vm.currentUser`. I have properties in my view that are data bound to it.